# TreeWidget setItemWidget Issue Qt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I am adding a `Qwidget`(`QPushButton`) into a `QTreeWidget` through `setItemWidget` method, but Button is not appearing as expected.

Need some help in this case.

Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Test_Ui(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test_Ui, self).__init__()
        self.setMainWidget()
        self.setTree()
        self.show()

    def setMainWidget(self):
        self.QwCentral = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.QwCentral)
        self.QglCentral = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.QwCentral.setLayout(self.QglCentral)

    def setTree(self):
        self.QtwExp = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.QtwExp.headerItem().setText(0, 'First')
        self.QtwExp.headerItem().setText(1, 'Second')
        self.QglCentral.addWidget(self.QtwExp, 0,0)

        Qcategory = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
        Qcategory.setText(0, 'TEST')
        self.QtwExp.addTopLevelItem(Qcategory)

        Qbutton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        Qbutton.setText('BUTTON')

        # setItem Widget Command
        self.QtwExp.setItemWidget(Qcategory, 1, Qbutton)

def main():
    global wapp
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wapp = Test_Ui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Where is `QglCentral`?

Comment: @ falsetru ... edited the question.. its a QGridLayout()

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo:

Replace following

```
self.QtwExp.addToplevelItem(Qcategory)
```

with

```
self.QtwExp.addTopLevelItem(Qcategory)
#                 ^
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for Typo... its still not working... have you tested the code?

Comment: @NarayaN, Did you call `main()` ?

Comment: Yess... its not working ...can u paste your output here ... as I am not able to open the image because of web violation policy at my end..

Comment: @NarayaN, I'm not sure. I am using *pyqt 4.9.3-4* in *Ubuntu 12.10*.

Answer (score 0):

Its the `PyQt4` version issue.
when i use `PyQt4` version 4.7.x it works fine.